# The command "Gulp build" exited with code 1

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to build a cloned project, but I'm getting an error:

> The command 'gulp build' exited with code 1".

First of all I had another error:

> The command 'build build' exited with code 9009

I realized that I need a gulp node module and installed it.

But after that, it's also exited with code 1.

I think that the problem is in NuGet Packages maybe, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install bower

```
npm install bower -g
```

Comment: npm install bower -g is the correct syntax